# Group dynamic - How can we take out from the "Storm" stage as soon as possible?

Tags: management, colleagues, team

I am working together with 3 guys close in a freshly created team I mean ~6+ months, we are mostly senior guys with one junior. We have separated environment and personal KPI-s. The work is given but our culture\vision\mission are a bit unsure and the recent work-flows\roles\future as well. So I recognized that we passed by the "Forming" stage when we were enjoying the "honeymoon" period and were excited about the newness. I think we reached the “Storming” stage where we are perceiving threats and problems. Politeness fades also and we  like to be honest as well as argue with others the difficulties, such as unclear formal roles\unclear objectives\external and internal threats and constant distractions.

Fortunately everybody is open about the new proposals at the company but the real execution is the hardest step in our process. We made some strides regarding the topic but I am feeling that we get stuck and I like to take out the team as soon as possible to the “Norm” and “Perform” stages.

My question is how can I increase speed of this period as well as reaching the next step and what could be the best communication regarding the topic?

I tried to summarize my situation in brief but if you have any extra question feel free to ask!

Comment: Please describe your problem in layman's terms, if you want people to help you. Not everybody subscribes to the group dynamics pattern that you cite informally, some may not even know about it.

Comment: what kind of extra information do you need? please give me a hint and I try to answer it.

Comment: not the team lead but I am in charge of improve the process and the inner communication. The management gave me plenty of rope so I could take the lead regarding relevant questions.

Answer (score 2):

This might be overly simple, but I find that success breeds success and that's it's important to have smaller (yet not ridiculously small) goals. Whenever I start a new project with a new team I try to be as blunt as possible that it's going to be a little rough until it gets smooth, there's just not a lot of way around that one.

So to speed it up I focus on getting through that let's-figure-out-how-to-really-work-with-each-other stage.

If you think about military teams or other tight-knit groups, that cohesion comes about from experience together. You don't all need to be best buddies, but you do need to know that you can rely on and trust each other. If there's a problem in that department, it's up to you as the leader to solve it quickly.

Get your team to have experience together and get something measurable and material accomplished. There will be a bit of blood on the walls, probably, and you'll need to be in booster mode. Also by picking a small goal, but not so small enough that it's obvious what you're doing, the schedule slide and possible need to rework it later isn't such a big deal.

Comment: I'm stealing "inchpebbles". Good one.

Comment: Your answer is validate my initiation to pick small and measurable goals as well as hit ”how-to-really-work-with-each-other”. I have another interesting situation some guys are working as a part time employee\student. 

What do you think about that? 

The process could be the same that you mentioned  or we have to change some points?

Comment: Joe Strazzere Can you tell me what you mean “inchpebbles”? Thank you